# Flutter : share a record

Tags: flutter, share, mp3, record

Im using [record_mp3 package](https://pub.dev/packages/record_mp3) to record an audio file, can i share this record via whatsapp and other social media ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share

code snippet

```
onPressed: () async {
          print('recordFilePath ${recordFilePath}');
          File file = File(recordFilePath);
          Uint8List bytes = await file.readAsBytes() as Uint8List;
          await Share.file(
              'yourmusic', 'yourmusic.mp3', bytes, 'audio/mpeg');
        }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:record_mp3/record_mp3.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:esys_flutter_share/esys_flutter_share.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String statusText = "";
  bool isComplete = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
          ),
          body: Column(children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 48.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red.shade300),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'start',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () async {
                      startRecord();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 48.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue.shade300),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          RecordMp3.instance.status == RecordStatus.PAUSE
                              ? 'resume'
                              : 'pause',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      pauseRecord();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 48.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green.shade300),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'stop',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      stopRecord();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                statusText,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
              onTap: () {
                play();
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                width: 100,
                height: 50,
                child: isComplete && recordFilePath != null
                    ? Text(
                        "播放",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                      )
                    : Container(),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              print('recordFilePath ${recordFilePath}');
              File file = File(recordFilePath);
              Uint8List bytes = await file.readAsBytes() as Uint8List;
              await Share.file(
                  'yourmusic', 'yourmusic.mp3', bytes, 'audio/mpeg');
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.share),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          )),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> checkPermission() async {
    Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> map = await new PermissionHandler()
        .requestPermissions(
            [PermissionGroup.storage, PermissionGroup.microphone]);
    print(map[PermissionGroup.microphone]);
    return map[PermissionGroup.microphone] == PermissionStatus.granted;
  }

  void startRecord() async {
    bool hasPermission = await checkPermission();
    if (hasPermission) {
      statusText = "正在录音中...";
      recordFilePath = await getFilePath();
      isComplete = false;
      RecordMp3.instance.start(recordFilePath, (type) {
        statusText = "录音失败--->$type";
        setState(() {});
      });
    } else {
      statusText = "没有录音权限";
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  void pauseRecord() {
    if (RecordMp3.instance.status == RecordStatus.PAUSE) {
      bool s = RecordMp3.instance.resume();
      if (s) {
        statusText = "正在录音中...";
        setState(() {});
      }
    } else {
      bool s = RecordMp3.instance.pause();
      if (s) {
        statusText = "录音暂停中...";
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
  }

  void stopRecord() {
    bool s = RecordMp3.instance.stop();
    if (s) {
      statusText = "录音已完成";
      isComplete = true;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void resumeRecord() {
    bool s = RecordMp3.instance.resume();
    if (s) {
      statusText = "正在录音中...";
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  String recordFilePath;

  void play() {
    if (recordFilePath != null && File(recordFilePath).existsSync()) {
      AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
      audioPlayer.play(recordFilePath, isLocal: true);
    }
  }

  int i = 0;

  Future<String> getFilePath() async {
    Directory storageDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String sdPath = storageDirectory.path + "/record";
    var d = Directory(sdPath);
    if (!d.existsSync()) {
      d.createSync(recursive: true);
    }
    return sdPath + "/test_${i++}.mp3";
  }
}
```

Comment: you are a life saver ^_^ ty ty